# mysql правильное хранение платежей

Tags: mysql, sql

Возник следующий вопрос: сервис продает определенные услуги. У каждой услуги есть несколько цен со своим сроком действия.

```
Service: id, name
Service_price: service_id, period, price
```

Таблица Service никогда не меняется. Как лучше хранить факты покупки данных услуг?

Варианты следующие:

1. В платеже дублировать информацию об услуге - хранить service_id, price и period.
2. В платеже хранить только ссылку на service_price_id

В первом варианте возникает избыточность.

Во втором варианте придется запретить изменять существующие данные в таблице (добавить поле is_active = false для устаревших цен) и разрешить только добавлять новые.

Какой подход более удобен и практичен? Данные по проданным услугам используются в отчетности с группировкой по периодам и ценам.

Comment: В один прекрасный день руководство внезапно поймет, что ему нужна история цен какой-нибудь услуги, и все равно придется делать таблицу по второму варианту. Поэтому, чтобы потом не переделывать, лучше сразу пойти по этому пути.

Comment: первый вариант. только период хранить незачем. у вас наверняка будет хранится дата платежа, ее достаточно что бы в случае чего посмотреть в справочнике какая цена должна была бы быть. С другой стороны при выдаче выходных форм вы вряд ли вообще будете использовать справочник цен, только реальную сумму, которая прошла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При реализации по варианту 2 достаточно, например, ввести скидку некоторым категориям клиентов, чтобы развалилось всё и сразу.

В данном случае имеет место ошибка анализа. Совокупность хранящихся в таблицах Service и Service_price данных представляет собой не справочник (данные-атрибуты) связанных со сведениями о платежах данных, а шаблон, который с платежами никак не связан (в момент создания записи о платеже связь между ней и использованным для её формирования шаблоном разрывается).

Так что только вариант 1. И это НЕ дублирование.